# Changing UIImage after click

Tags: swift

I have 13 images named `1` to `13` in my project. I would like the `UIImageView` to change from image 1 to 2, then 3, then 4 and so on, at the click of a `UIButton`.

My current code when the `UIButton` is clicked:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: Any) {
    cardImage.image = UIImage(named: 1)
}
```

So I know I need to store the value in a variable and initially set the value to 1. Add 1 to the value every time I click the `UIButton`. That value needs to be somehow linked to `cardImage.Image = UIImage`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you'd really benefit from going through a few basic tutorials - looks like you need to learn some pretty basic stuff like variables... But persevere! There are some great tutorials out there & if you work at them you'll wonder why you ever thought this was hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your current image number value in a variable and increase in when the button is pressed.

```
let imagesCount: Int = 13
var currentImageNumber: Int = 1

@IBAction func didPressButton(sender: Any) {
    cardImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(currentImageNumber)")
    currentImageNumber += 1
    if currentImageNumber > imagesCount {
        currentImageNumber = 1
    }
}
```

Or you can use a shorter version without `if` condition.

```
let imagesCount: Int = 13
var currentImageNumber: Int = 0

@IBAction func didPressButton(sender: Any) {
    cardImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(currentImageNumber + 1)")
    currentImageNumber += 1
    currentImageNumber %= imagesCount
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me :D

Comment: Why the down-vote? This seems like a reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: Wouldn't your "no if statement" code start at image though?

Comment: @DuncanC What do you mean by *start at image*?

Comment: Sorry, start at image 2. The first image it will load will be named "2".

Comment: Yeah. I supposed that `UIImageView` already has an image and it only has to be changed after the button is pressed. I've read the question again and you're right. I'll change my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So create an array of your filenames in your view controller, and an index into that array:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var filenames: [String] = {
        return Array(1...13).map {String($0)}
    }()

    var filenameIndex = 0
```

Then write a function to load one of your images and increment the index:

```
    func fetchImage() -> UIImage? {
         let result = UIImage(named: filenames[filenameIndex])
         filenameIndex = (filenameIndex + 1) % filenames.count
         return result
    }
```

(You could also use Yury's approach of managing an integer index and converting that to a filename, but my approach will let you manage cycling through any array of image filenames, whether they are sequential numbers or not.)